# Zend Db connection and configuration

Tags: database, zend-framework, pdo, adapter

I'm developing a zend application.I have in "config.ini":

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root"
resources.db.params.dbname = "test"
```

**To start a connection with my Db and query it what else should I set?**

Thanks

Luca

Comment: What have you tried?  What hasn't worked for you?  [Have you reviewed the documentation on Zend_Db and how it can interact with Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.connecting.factory-config)?

Comment: thats what I needed!thanks I'm half following a book half the web.So it confuses me sometime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize your connection in the bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
    protected function _initDatabase(){
        // get config from config/application.ini
        $config = $this->getOptions();

        $db = Zend_Db::factory($config['resources']['db']['adapter'], $config['resources']['db']['params']);

        //set default adapter
        Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);

        //save Db in registry for later use
        Zend_Registry::set("db", $db);
    }
}
```

You don't have to save the connection in the registry.

Comment: This doesn't work in certain circumstances because the auto-initialization of "resources" will overwrite what ever is set here. You would want to store the database information in the ini file somewhere else besides "resources.db"

Answer (score 2):

Create a database model file in your `application/models/Data.php`

```
class Model_Data extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

    protected $_name='myDatabse'; //the database name
    /**
     * Create new entry
     *     
     */
    public function create($title,$author,$authorUrl,$category){
        $row=$this->createRow();
        $row->title=$title;
        $row->author=$author;
        $row->site=$authorUrl;
        $row->category=$category;
        $row->save();
        return $this->_db->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

Declare the models in your `bootstrap.php` file like so:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoLoader=Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $resourceLoader=new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'=>APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace'=>'',
            'resourceTypes'=>array(                
                'models'=>array(
                    'path'=>'models/',
                    'namespace'=>'Model_'
                ),                
            )
            ));


        $autoLoader->pushAutoloader($resourceLoader);       
    }
}
```

Then make queries via your controller action:

```
class SearchController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {        
       $dataModel=new Model_Data();
       $dataModel->create("title","author","url","category");       

    }


}
```